C++ Code doesn't give any output and stuck
I am making a lexer & parser for a 8 bit cpu, my lexer is working fine but when I added AST class for parse, this problem started. Whats the problem and how to solve it
The code takes a string input, lexer class then split it into tokens and pass the vector of tokens to parser.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// Token Types
enum TokenType {
    KEYWORD, OPERATOR, BRACE, SEMICOLON, IDENTIFIER, LITERAL, END_OF_FILE
};

// Token Structure
struct Token {
    TokenType type;
    string value;

    Token(TokenType type, const string &value) : type(type), value(value) {}
};

// Lexer Class
class Lexer {
    string input;
    size_t position;
    
    // Helper to check if a string is a keyword
    bool isKeyword(const string &str) {
        return str == "int" || str == "if";
    }

    // Read the next character
    char peek() {
        if (position >= input.length()) return '\0';
        return input[position];
    }

    // Advance the current position
    char advance() {
        return input[position++];
    }

    // Skip over whitespace
    void skipWhitespace() {
        while (isspace(peek())) advance();
    }

    // Main function to tokenize input
    vector<Token> tokenize() {
        vector<Token> tokens;
        while (position < input.length()) {
            skipWhitespace();
            char current = peek();

            if (isalpha(current)) {  // Identifiers and Keywords
                string identifier = "";
                while (isalnum(peek())) {
                    identifier += advance();
                }
                if (isKeyword(identifier)) {
                    tokens.emplace_back(KEYWORD, identifier);
                } else {
                    tokens.emplace_back(IDENTIFIER, identifier);
                }
            } 
            else if (isdigit(current)) {  // Literals (Numbers)
                string literal = "";
                while (isdigit(peek())) {
                    literal += advance();
                }
                tokens.emplace_back(LITERAL, literal);
            } 
            else if (current == ';') {  // Semicolon
                tokens.emplace_back(SEMICOLON, ";");
                advance();
            } 
            else if (current == '{' || current == '}') {  // Braces
                tokens.emplace_back(BRACE, string(1, current));
                advance();
            } 
            else if (current == '(' || current == ')') {  // Parentheses
                tokens.emplace_back(BRACE, string(1, current));  // You might want to introduce a new TokenType like PAREN to distinguish between braces and parentheses
                advance();
            }
            else if (current == '=' || current == '+' || current == '-') {  // Operators
                string op = "";
                op += advance();
                if (peek() == '=') {  // Handle '=='
                    op += advance();
                }
                tokens.emplace_back(OPERATOR, op);
            } 
            else if (current == '\0') {  // End of input
                tokens.emplace_back(END_OF_FILE, "");
                break;
            } 
            else {
                cerr << "Unexpected character: " << current << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        return tokens;
    }

public:
    Lexer(const string &input) : input(input), position(0) {}
    
    vector<Token> getTokens() {
        return tokenize();
    }
}; //Lexer class ends


// AST Node Base Class
struct ASTNode {
    virtual ~ASTNode() = default;
};

// Variable Declaration Node
struct VarDeclNode : public ASTNode {
    string varName;

    VarDeclNode(const string &varName) : varName(varName) {}
};

// Assignment Node
struct AssignmentNode : public ASTNode {
    string varName;
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> expression;

    AssignmentNode(const string &varName, shared_ptr<ASTNode> expression)
        : varName(varName), expression(expression) {}
};

// Binary Operation Node
struct BinOpNode : public ASTNode {
    string op;
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> left, right;

    BinOpNode(const string &op, shared_ptr<ASTNode> left, shared_ptr<ASTNode> right)
        : op(op), left(left), right(right) {}
};

// Literal Node
struct LiteralNode : public ASTNode {
    int value;

    LiteralNode(int value) : value(value) {}
};

// Identifier (Variable) Node
struct IdentifierNode : public ASTNode {
    string name;

    IdentifierNode(const string &name) : name(name) {}
};

// Conditional (If) Node
struct IfNode : public ASTNode {
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> condition;
    vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> body;

    IfNode(shared_ptr<ASTNode> condition, vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> body)
        : condition(condition), body(body) {}
};

// Parser Class
class Parser {
    vector<Token> tokens;
    size_t position;

    // Utility functions
    Token peek() {
        if (position >= tokens.size()) return Token(END_OF_FILE, "");
        return tokens[position];
    }

    Token advance() {
        return tokens[position++];
    }

    bool match(TokenType type) {
        if (peek().type == type) {
            advance();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Parse a program (sequence of statements)
    vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> parseProgram() {
        vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> statements;
        while (peek().type != END_OF_FILE) {
            statements.push_back(parseStatement());
        }
        return statements;
    }

    // Parse a statement
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parseStatement() {
        if (match(KEYWORD)) {
            string keyword = tokens[position - 1].value;
            if (keyword == "int") {
                return parseVarDecl();
            } else if (keyword == "if") {
                return parseIf();
            }
        } else if (peek().type == IDENTIFIER) {
            return parseAssignment();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Parse variable declaration
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parseVarDecl() {
        string varName = advance().value;  // Identifier after "int"
        match(SEMICOLON);  // Expect semicolon
        return make_shared<VarDeclNode>(varName);
    }

    // Parse assignment
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parseAssignment() {
        string varName = advance().value;  // Identifier
        match(OPERATOR);  // Expect '=' operator
        auto expr = parseExpression();
        match(SEMICOLON);  // Expect semicolon
        return make_shared<AssignmentNode>(varName, expr);
    }

    // Parse an expression
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parseExpression() {
        auto left = parsePrimary();
        if (peek().type == OPERATOR && (peek().value == "+" || peek().value == "-")) {
            string op = advance().value;
            auto right = parsePrimary();
            return make_shared<BinOpNode>(op, left, right);
        }
        return left;  // If no binary operator, return the primary expression
    }

    // Parse primary expression (identifier or literal)
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parsePrimary() {
        if (match(LITERAL)) {
            return make_shared<LiteralNode>(stoi(tokens[position - 1].value));
        } else if (match(IDENTIFIER)) {
            return make_shared<IdentifierNode>(tokens[position - 1].value);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Parse conditional (if) statement
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> parseIf() {
        match(BRACE);  // Expect '('
        auto condition = parseExpression();
        match(BRACE);  // Expect ')'

        match(BRACE);  // Expect '{'
        vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> body;
        while (!match(BRACE)) {
            body.push_back(parseStatement());
        }
        return make_shared<IfNode>(condition, body);
    }

public:
    Parser(const vector<Token> &tokens) : tokens(tokens), position(0) {}

    vector<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> parse() {
        return parseProgram();
    }
};

// Test the lexer
int main() {
    string code = "int a; a = 10; if (a == 10) { a = a + 1; }";
        cout<<"Lexer not Completed";

    Lexer lexer(code);
    vector<Token> tokens = lexer.getTokens();
    cout<<"Lexer Completed";
    Parser parser(tokens);  // Pass tokens to the parser
    auto ast = parser.parse();  // Parse the tokens into an AST

    cout << "Parsing completed successfully!" << endl;
    return 0;
}


I thought it had something to do with shared_ptr or  library, but its not that I guess.

parseExpression believes that only + and - are valid operators, but the program also uses ==. Once the stream of tokens deviates from what the parser expects, parseStatement() returns null without advancing, and parseProgram spins in a loop, pushing nulls into the vector.

Instead of giving us hundreds of lines, try to make it on-point and minimal. Use gdb to figure out where it actually stucks, this will help us to help you.
